# Auto generate text in rich textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

Right now im making an app where you write in some text and push a button.
My Question is: how i can make that when you for write something in a textbox then it ads something more like this?

**Example**
If the person write:

```
12324
```

then i want to make that it shows:

```
1-2-3-2-4
```

Like a listener that that add things into the textbox if you write something.

Thankful for help.

Comment: You could listen to the event "TextChanged" and *then* modify the text.

Comment: Yes but i want also to make something so it can see if its 8 letters then it sets a "-" after every 4 letter..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using TextChange Event.

Here is an Example

```
private void txtPenaltyDays_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string yourText = txtPenaltyDays.Text;
    txtPenaltyDays_1.Text = string.Join("-", yourText.ToCharArray())
}
```

Assuming you have two textBoxes

- txtPenaltyDays
- txtPenaltyDays_1

**Update:-**
instead of the single character, you can add "-" after every 4th character.

```
string a = "mihirdaveisdeveloper";

var divided = Enumerable.Range(0, a.Length / 4)
                .Select(i => a.Substring(i * 4, 4));
var ans = string.Join("-", divided);
```

Comment: But if i want it to add "-" after 4 letters? can i do that? Does this make it one time or multiple times?

Comment: You can write, whatever logic you want inside "TextChanged" event and it triggers every time you add or remove char from your textBox

Comment: If you want it after 4 characters just check the textbox length before setting it.

Comment: Okey, do you have any example how to make that possible? so it adds "-" after every four letter